# $\varphi : \mathbb{C}^*\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^*$ is defined by $\varphi(x+iy)=x^2+y^2$, what is the image and kernel of $\varphi$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm hopeful that I proved the homomorphism stating:

$$\varphi((x+iy)(a+ib))=(x^2+y^2)(a^2+b^2)=\varphi(x+iy)\varphi(a+bi)\label1\tag1$$

Now I want to show what the kernel and image of $\varphi$ is (I haven't taken complex analysis). I've read that the $\ker\varphi$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$ in this case and that the $\ker\varphi$ is the set of {$x \in G\mid\varphi(x)=e$}. Then that might suggest that $\ker\varphi= \lbrace x, y \in \mathbb{C}^*\mid x^2+y^2=e=1 \rbrace = \left\lbrace \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right\rbrace$ because of $x^2$ we will always have 1--the identity. Since I think $\mathbb{R}^* \subset \mathbb{C}^*$, then the image of $\varphi$ is $\mathbb{R}^*$?

I would like to know if I missed anything crucial. Thanks!

Comment: The kernel is the preimage of the identity in $\mathbb{R}^*$. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: Your kernel has only $2$ elements?

Comment: You do not seem to say it, but context suggests that $x$ and $y$ are demanded real; then the complex plane minus the origin is where $x,y$ are not both zero.

Comment: The kernel is just the complex numbers with module equal to $1$. The last equality is false. And the image of $\varphi$ is the set of positive real numbers, not the whole $\mathbb R^*$.

Comment: @Dog_69 yeeaaah.. I was a little sloppy with that actually... you're right the image is just $R_+$.

Comment: @dls nice :). got you  the part of the kernel?

Comment: Your proof that it is a homomorphism makes no sense. To calculate $\varphi(z)$ you need to write $z$ in the form $x+iy$. It's wrong to simply write $\varphi((x+iy)(a+ib))=(x^2+y^2)(a^2+b^2)$.

Comment: @Dog_69 actually I'm kind of lost finding the kernel.. everyone quickly got me reviewing complex numbers and I figured I now have to solve for $(a+bi)^2=1$ and what I originally thought to be the kernel gave me just $i$ which wasn't really close haha..

Comment: @Mark I'm actually not sure what I skipped. I figured now that $z=a+bi$ but I was given $\varphi(x+iy)=x^2+y^2$. Is there something about complex numbers that I need to know to solve this problem other than knowing $i^2=-1$ and that $z=a+bi$?

Comment: @dls. No. You are lookinf for the kernel of $\varphi$, so you have to solve for $\varphi(x+iy)=x^2+y^2=1$. Now you can revise the polar form of complex numbers to get a closed form for the kernel. For instance, Mark is right in his comment about the first proof regarding homomorphism.

Comment: But why did you write $\varphi((x+iy)(a+ib))=(x^2+y^2)(a^2+b^2)$? The expression $(x+iy)(a+ib)$ is not written in the correct form. The correct way to do that is to note that $(x+iy)(a+ib)=xa+ixb+iya-yb=(xa-yb)+i(xb+ya)$. And now we get $\varphi((x+iy)(a+ib))=\varphi((xa-yb)+i(xb+ya))=(xa-yb)^2+(xb+ya)^2$. And now your goal is to prove that it equals to $\varphi(x+iy)\varphi(a+ib)=(x^2+y^2)(a^2+b^2)$.

Comment: @Mark thanks for your explanation. I believe I understand it now. I have solved it with your and Dog_69's help I guess my biggest mistake was assuming I could just use $(x+iy)(a+ib)$ in the function. The reason why I can't is because it isn't in the form of z=a+ib and if I wanted $zv, v=a+ib$ then $zv=(x+iy)(a+ib)=(xa-yb)+i(xb+ya)$ .

Comment: @dls Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Dog_69 am I not able to solve for 1 if I do not use the polar form? I'm looking at the polar form on the complex plane, $z=rcos \theta +i(rsin\theta)$ and I'm not sure how to move forward from here.

Comment: @dls in theory you have already find the kernel. But notices that in the polar form, the condition $x^2+y^2=1$ means $r^2=1$. Then the kernel are the complex numbers $z$ of the form $z=\cos t +i \sin t$, or just $z=e^{it}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've distorted the definition of the kernel a bit.  You should have
$$
\ker \varphi = \{z \in \Bbb C^* \mid \varphi(z) = 1\}
$$
Because every complex number can be written as $z = x + iy$ for $x,y \in \Bbb R$, we can rewrite this as
$$
\ker \varphi = \{x + iy \mid x \in \Bbb R, y \in \Bbb R, x^2 + y^2 = 1\}
$$
which is to say that the kernel of $\varphi$ is the unit circle in the complex plane.

As for the image, note that $\Bbb R^*$ includes the negative numbers, which do not lie in the image of $\varphi$.  You can use your idea, however, to show that every positive real lies in the image of $\varphi$.  In particular: if $x$ is real and positive, then $x \in \Bbb R^* \subset \Bbb C^*$ and we have $\varphi(\sqrt{x}) = x$.

Comment: I think what is missing is that $x,y$ should be required real in the definitions.

Comment: @WillJagy $z = x+iy$ is such common language in complex analysis, is it really necessary to specify that $x,y$ are real?

Comment: @WillJagy I think it is just a reminder because I have not taken CA before.

Comment: @DougM Given that OP's answer begins $\{x,y \in \Bbb C^*\dots$, I think that it is a useful clarification.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom may I ask how the $\ker\varphi$ is found? I'm not sure how to start it. Basically $x$ and $y$ has to equal 1 in $\mathbb{R}^*$ however because it is the in the preimage then I can have elements with $i$ right?

Comment: @dls I don't know what you mean by "basically $x$ and $y$ has to equal 1 in $\Bbb R^*$".  Could you try to explain what you mean a bit more precisely?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom sorry yeah that was definitely not clear. I mean that I need and $x$ and $y$ s.t. $x^2+y^2=1$ however I could only come up with my original set of $\lbrace \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \rbrace$. Can I set $x+iy=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and solve for the complexed values I maybe missing? I don't have an intuitive sense of what I am missing in my set or why my set is wrong.

Comment: @dls I don't understand what you're doing with the set $\lbrace \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \rbrace$; your set is a set of two real numbers, but the set that we're looking for contains a bunch of complex numbers.  I would agree that the complex number $\frac 1{\sqrt 2} - \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}i$ is an element of $\ker \varphi$; perhaps this is what you're getting at.  Another element of $\ker \varphi$ is $1 + 0i$.  More generally, $\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ will be an element of $\ker \varphi$ for any angle $\theta$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom that's very helpful, my original set is wrong I guess. I wasn't sure how to come across elements in the kernel at the moment because I don't know how to solve for the complex numbers you've suggested. I might have to look into complex analysis.

Comment: @dls The number $x + iy$ is in the kernel whenever the point $(x,y)$ is on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, that's really all that needs to be said for the purposes of answering the question.